# Do enough rude/offensive flags auto-delete a comment?

Tags: support, comment-flags

I know that if a *post* accumulates six offensive (or spam) flags it is auto-deleted.  What happens with comments?  Do enough "rude or offensive" flags on a comment also auto-delete it?  (Spam isn't a flag reason for comments.)  If so, what is the threshold?

If comments can be auto-deleted by flags, do reasons other than rude/offensive trigger it too, or just that one?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I know that "off topic" flags will check automatically and delete if applicable. That is one other one at least.

Comment: Short answer, "yes". All comment flags.

Comment: see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work ("Who can delete comments")

Comment: @Geobits thanks -- *just* found that, two hops away (so I'll close as a dupe).  I had searched for "rude flags" and "rude comments" before asking but didn't turn that up.